# i can't expand my ext:gridpanel

Tags: asp.net, ext.net, coolite

i have gridpanel in my page and i want to expand it (somthing like height=100%) but i can't find any property that can use 
this is my code

this is my code :

```
   <ext:Panel runat="server"    ID="pnlEest">
           <Body>
           <div>
               <ext:FitLayout  ID="FitLayout1" runat="server">
                   <ext:GridPanel   ID="GridPanel1" runat="server" StoreID="Store1" >
                       <TopBar>
                           <ext:Toolbar ID="ToolBar1" runat="server">
                               <Items>
                                   <ext:Button ID="BtnInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" IconCls="Button_Add">
                                       <AjaxEvents>
                                           <Click OnEvent="BtnInsert_Click">
                                               <EventMask ShowMask="true" />
                                           </Click>
                                       </AjaxEvents>
                                   </ext:Button>
                                   <ext:Button ID="BtnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" IconCls="Button_Add">
                                       <Listeners>
                                           <Click Handler="#{GridPanel1}.reload();" />
                                       </Listeners>
                                   </ext:Button>
                                   <ext:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" IconCls="Button_Add">
                                       <Listeners>
                                           <Click Handler="#{GridPanel1}.reload();" />
                                       </Listeners>
                                   </ext:Button>
                               </Items>
                           </ext:Toolbar>
                       </TopBar>
                      <ColumnModel  ID="ColumnModel1"  runat="server">
                           <Columns>
                               <ext:RowNumbererColumn />

                               <ext:Column ColumnID="IDField" DataIndex="Id" Header="Id" Sortable="true" Width="50"
                                   Hidden="true">
                                   <PrepareCommand Handler="" Args="grid,command,record,row,col,value" FormatHandler="False">
                                   </PrepareCommand>
                                   <PrepareCommands Handler="" Args="grid,commands,record,row,col,value" FormatHandler="False">
                                   </PrepareCommands>
                               </ext:Column>


                               <ext:Column DataIndex="LocalName" Header="LocalName" Sortable="true" Width="120">
                                   <PrepareCommand Handler="" Args="grid,command,record,row,col,value" FormatHandler="False">
                                   </PrepareCommand>
                                   <PrepareCommands Handler="" Args="grid,commands,record,row,col,value" FormatHandler="False">
                                   </PrepareCommands>
                               </ext:Column>
                               <ext:Column DataIndex="LatinName" Header="LatinName" Sortable="true" Width="120">
                                   <PrepareCommand Handler="" Args="grid,command,record,row,col,value" FormatHandler="False">
                                   </PrepareCommand>
                                   <PrepareCommands Handler="" Args="grid,commands,record,row,col,value" FormatHandler="False">
                                   </PrepareCommands>
                               </ext:Column>


                           </Columns>
                       </ColumnModel>
                      <SelectionModel>
                           <ext:RowSelectionModel ID="RowSelectionModel1" runat="server" />
                       </SelectionModel>
                      <LoadMask ShowMask="true" />
                      <BottomBar>
                           <ext:PagingToolbar Cls="DataGrid_Footer" ID="PagingToolBar1" runat="server" DisplayInfo="True"
                               DisplayMsg="Documents {0} - {1} OF {2}" PageSize="2" StoreID="Store1" />
                       </BottomBar>
                   </ext:GridPanel>
               </ext:FitLayout>
           </div>
           </Body>
       </ext:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this with add

```
    <ext:ViewPort runat="server" Cls="test">
               <Body>
                   <ext:FitLayout  ID="FitLayout1" runat="server" >
```

instead of

```
  <ext:Panel runat="server"    ID="pnlEest">   
       <Body>   
       <div>   
           <ext:FitLayout  ID="FitLayout1" runat="server">
```